# PHP - JSON, ввозврат нескольких строк

Tags: php, json

Хочу получить ответ в виде JSON.

Пишу такой скрипт, к которому и обращаюсь:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1242380_reminduser", "rootroot", "id1242380_remindtbase");

    $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE user_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $user_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $user_id, $title, $text);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;;

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true; 
        $response["id"] = $id; 
        $response["user_id"] = $user_id;
        $response["title"] = $title;
        $response["text"] = $text;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Но в ответе получаю только одну строку из бд (последнюю). Вот Logcat:

> 11-04 20:14:15.392 11578-11578/com.example.aydar.remind D/RESPONSETAG: onResponse: {"success":true,"id":3,"user_id":1,"title":"test_title2","text":"test_text2"}

Хотя в БД записано 3 записи и у всеx отличие только в двух последних полях. Поэтому запросу они все удовлетворяют. В чём тут дело?

Comment: `$response[$id][...`

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть через var_dump(), переменную $response.
Скорее всего вам нужно будет обращаться по индексу.

Comment: А может всё дело в том, что Вы не "получаете" одну строку, а **выводите** одну строку? И рекомендую Вам прямо сходу завязывать с записыванием success-ов при чтении из базы данных. В самом деле, хоть раз у кого-нибудь был не success?

Comment: Вывожу я таким образом
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("RESPONSETAG", "onResponse: " + jsonObject);
,так что скорее всего (почти точно) я вывожу весь JSON

Comment: @YaroslavPavlinskiy
если использовать $response[$id][...] = $...;, то Java вылетает из try при попытке получить JSONObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы объявляете `$response` как массив в **PHP**. При конвертации в JSON массив преобразуется в объект `{}` или список `[]` в зависимости от того ассоциативный ли массив. в цикле `while(fetch)` вы обходите все записи из БД и записываете значения в поля `$response['id']` и т.д. Всё бы ничего, но с каждой новой итерацией while предыдущие данные перезаписываются новыми.

Приведу простой пример вашей нынешней логики без БД и циклов:

```
$a = 5;
$a = 10;
$a = 7;
echo $a; // Выведет 7. Логично? логично!
```

Я понятия не имею как вы до этого дошли, но вот простое решение вашей проблемы:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id1242380_reminduser', 'rootroot', 'id1242380_remindtbase');

$user_id = (int) $_POST['user_id'];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE user_id = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'i', $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $user_id, $title, $text);

$response = ['success' => false];

$rows = [];
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
  $rows[] = [
    'id' => $id,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'title' => $title,
    'text' => $text
  ];
}

if(sizeof($rows)) {
  $response['success'] = true;
  $response['response'] = $rows;
}

echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

В ответе вы получите что-то подобное:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "response": [{
      "id": 5,
      "user_id": 21354,
      "title": "Купить кегли",
      "text": "Кегли - это очень важно. Нужно их купить."
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "user_id": 21354,
      "title": "Волчанка",
      "text": "Саре нужны кортикостероиды."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это действительно сработало.
Своё "решение" я взял из обучалок в инете. Впредь буду больше уделять времени на документацию.
Ещё раз спасибо